# How can we customize the Page Information menu options on experience fragments in AEM 6.5?

Tags: aem

I've managed to customize the Page Information menu options for pages, but experience fragments seem to fall under a different category. Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of this page?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Additionally, sharing both the current and desired result of your try will allow community members to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

So, managed to figure it out.
I locally overwrote the content of:

```
/apps/cq/experience-fragments/content/editor/jcr:content/content/items/content/header/items/headerbar/items/pageinfopopover/items/list/items
```

in the `content.xml` file.

[image: Added menu option]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).